# Pour In On / Pour Into

Tags: prepositions, intransitive-preposition

I have a question about the usage of the phrase "*pour in*" [here](http://news.yahoo.com/jimmy-carter-says-cancer-revealed-recent-surgery-203826345.html):

> Carter announced on Aug. 3 that he had surgery to remove a small mass from his liver.  ***Good wishes poured in on social media*** after Carter's announcement, while President Barack Obama said he and first lady Michelle Obama wish Carter a fast and full recovery.

What if "*poured in on*" is replaced with "*poured into*"?  How is:

> good wishes poured ***in on*** social media.

different from:

> good wishes poured ***into*** social media.

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what's going on, you need to (mentally) re-arrange the sentences:

> [Good wishes] [poured in] [on social media].

With

- **poured in** meaning "*arrived* (at Carter's) en masse" or "there *came* lots of them" and
- **on social media** defining the channel (Twitter, facebook...) over which the wishes were sent.

If you change it to:

> [Good wishes] [(were) poured] [into social media].

The wishes were *sent* towards social media channels. You don't write about *arriving* any more. Also you somewhat loose the emphasis on the great number of good wishes. And you would be missing a verb (wishes don't pour themselves), which I included above.

Comment: The second phrase is correct, however it is ambiguous. I would be inclined to get rid of "were", leaving "Good wishes poured into social media" - It is a completed action. In this case, the wishes may pour themselves, as no person is noted as pouring them - i.e. the subject is the "good wishes" and they were poured. I can understand why you used "were", however in this case, it doesn't seem to fit, and you should stick to the past simple. But good answer :-)